# Fenics: problem with the mesh generation

Tags: fenics

while executing my script i get this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/oss/Fenics/demo/box_3delasticity.py", line 33, in 
    mesh = Box (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dolfin/cpp/mesh.py", line 8698, in **init**
    _mesh.Box_swiginit(self,_mesh.new_Box(*args)

I don't know exactly how to fix this bug??

Comment: Please, deliver the error message too - not only the traceback. And you probably have to provide more information on what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mesh = BoxMesh(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

The name of the class has been changed from Box to BoxMesh.

The class Box is now something different: a geometric primitive which can be used for defining and geometries used as input for the DOLFIN mesh generator.

Comment: thnks it solved my problem